# ReactJS modal window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have no idea how to make my app work. 
I have a component `ContactAdd` that `onClick` must render component `ModalWindow`. `ModalWindow` has a parameter `isOpened={this.state.open}`. How to control this state from parent component?

```
import React from 'react';

import ContactAddModal from './ContactAddModal.jsx';

import './ContactAdd.css';

export default class ContactAdd extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="add-contact" onClick={ ??????? }>
                <img src="./img/add.png" />
                <ContactAddModal/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}




import React from 'react';

export default class ContactAddModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: false,
        };
        this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
    }

    handleCloseModal () {
        this.setState({ show: false });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="modal" isOpened={this.state.show}>
                <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: See [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).

Answer (score 0):

Making the modal a stateless component might be simpler here. The tradeoff being that you would have to handle the closing for every modal, which I think is acceptable. This answer is just an option and by no means an absolute truth.

It could look something like that

```
export default class ContactAdd extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal: true
        };
        this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
    }

    hideModal() {
        this.setState({
            showModal: false
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="add-contact">
                <img src="./img/add.png" />
                <ContactAddModal handleClose={this.hideModal} isOpened={this.state.showModal} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Now the modal:

```
export default class ContactAddModal extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="modal" isOpened={this.props.isOpened}>
                <button onClick={this.props.handleClose}>Close Modal</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Now I have a problem with changing state.
function from modal-component is working, but don't want change state/.